# Not Able to get graph using cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am following this github project : [Here](https://github.com/kevinzhow/PNChart).In that they mentioned to do :

```
Cocoapods

CocoaPods is the recommended way to add PNChart to your project.

Add a pod entry for PNChart to your Podfile pod 'PNChart'
Install the pod(s) by running pod install.
Include PNChart wherever you need it with #import "PNChart.h".
```

What i did is :

1. start the new project and add all frame works.
2. then i use terminal to create podfile like ( touch podfile )
3. then i move to my project folder to podfile file and i add this code

   `pod 'PNChart', '~> 0.8.7'`
4. Then i use pod install to run .
5. then i add PNChart folder to my project, after that when i build i am not able to see my graph.

But when i download their project from github , then when i see their podfile file .its like this below code:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

    platform :ios, '6.0'
    pod 'UICountingLabel','~> 1.2.0'

    target :PNChartTests do
        pod 'Expecta'
    end
```

But when i copy these files to my podfile and when i run `pod install` in terminal . i am getting error `no PNChartTest are seen`

What i need to do first to work with line graph. please some one guid me to do,thanks!

**UPDATED:**

Error occur in this file : `PNRadarChartDataItem.h`- this file will be inside the PNChart folder

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface PNRadarChartDataItem : NSObject

+ (instancetype)dataItemWithValue:(CGFloat)value
                      description:(NSString *)description;

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat   value;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *textDescription;

@end
```

3 error :

1. error in this line `+ (instancetype)dataItemWithValue:(CGFloat)value
                     description:(NSString *)description`

   **error : Expected a type**
2. error in this line `- (void)setValue:(CGFloat)value {`

   **error : Expected a type**
3. error in this line `@property (nonatomic) CGFloat   value;`

   **error : unknow type name cgfloat**

Answer (score 0):

- Create new project.
- Right click on 'Xcode project' in Xcode project navigator and choose others & empty file name 'Podfile' and select the destination as project directory level (Podfile should be at the xcodeproject file level) and add following lines

  ```
  pod 'PNChart'
  ```
- Close xcodeproject
- Go to project directory and run the 'pod install' command from the termial
- Open workspace i.e. .xcworkspace file
- Import charts file in view controller such as

  ```
  #import "ViewController.h" 

  #import "PNChart.h"
  ```

Added [sample project here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ws0ev96rh1u86d/TestPNChartPod.zip?dl=0).

Comment: then why in their git hub project the added `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

    platform :ios, '6.0'
    pod 'UICountingLabel','~> 1.2.0'

    target :PNChartTests do
        pod 'Expecta'
    end` files . And one more question i have to drop whole project to my project or  only i have  to drag and drop `PNChart`

Comment: No need to drop `PNChart` folder to my project or what??

Comment: i did what you said. but error occur.please see my updated post

Comment: Drag and drop PNChart folder into your project then add Podfile. In the instruction, it is mention add line pod "PNChart' to Podfile, not what is in the library's podfile.

Comment: i did all but get this error `error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`

Comment: Can you show me what linking error are you getting? I tried the same steps mentioned above its working fine for me.

Comment: where i can see that part. i am getting this error `error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` . which i saw in `show the issues navigator ` at left pannel

Comment: error : `ld: 235 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: if you have done with no error .can you please post this two files code in your answer part `PNRadarChartDataItem.h` `PNRadarChartDataItem.m`

Comment: Either just try by removing 'PNChart' folder from your project(make sure all references should be removed) or create new project and try. Problem is in the project settings.

Comment: did you tried that project. does it work well for you??

Comment: Yes its working as expected, I tried graph as well its drawing properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97111/discussion-between-anni-s-and-maddey).